# delete query with correlated subquery throwing error

Tags: sybase-ase15

DELETE
FROM cats c
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
FROM owner_cats o
WHERE o.id_cat = c.id_cat
AND o.id_owner = 1)

Tables names are different.  This is throwing sybase errror 107.
The column prefix '%.*s' does not match with a table name or alias name used in the query. Either the table is not specified in the FROM clause or it has a correlation name which must be used instead.
Explanation.

Everything seems to b e  correct with query. Please help.

Comment: Table names are different means I mean i  have not used the actuall tables name here.

Answer (score 0):

You gotta change it to DELETE cats FROM cats c (etc).

Comment: It's just how the syntax goes in ASE. The different SQL dialects actually  allowing correlation names in different ways that have no logical explanation: the dialects have just grown in different ways.